# Vertical menu opens upward?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, vb.net

Real quick, seems like kind of a dumb question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I need a vertical menu that pops up out of the footer and goes up the screen.

I've been looking at the Ajax Collapsible Panel Extender but can't get it to go up instead of down.

I'm limited to the software already loaded in the virtual profile I have here at work (no admin, can't get cool new things) so if it's something available in CSS, VB.NET, ASP or AJAX that would be spiffy, otherwise I'll need to find something else to do.

What I'm looking for is a control I can use to have a menu appear upwards instead of downwards. Thanks.

**HTML** For side menu: (Like this, but in the footer and opening towards the header)

```
<asp:ImageButton class="Header-Cart" ID="imgCart" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/Mobile/mobile-header-cart.png" onclick="imgCart_Click" />
        </div>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlNavMenu"  class="Mobile-Menu" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <div class="Search-Block"><div class="search-textbox"><div>
                       <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" class="Search-Icon"
                            BackColor="White"  runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/Mobile/mobile-search-icon.png" />
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="Search" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Enter keyword or product code'; isSet=true; }"
                            onmouseover="if(this.value == 'Enter keyword or product code') { this.value='';isSet = true; }"
                            onmouseout="if(this.value == '' && !isSet) { this.value='Enter keyword or product code'; isSet=>false; }"
                            MaxLength="255" Text="Enter keyword or product code" ontextchanged="btnSearch_Click"/>
                       <asp:ImageButton ID="btnClear" class="Search-Cancel" BackColor="White" runat="server" OnClick="btnClear_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/Mobile/mobile-search-cancel.png" />
                        </div>
             </div> 
             </div>
              <div class="Nav-Item">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlShop" runat="server">
                    <div class="Menu-Panel-Header"><asp:Label ID="lblShopBtn" runat="server" Text="Shop" /></div>
                    <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlComputers" runat="server" Text="Computers" NavigateUrl="/Computers/Index.aspx" /></div>
                    <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlElectronics" runat="server" Text="Electronics" NavigateUrl="/Electronics/Index.aspx" /></div>
                    <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlExLease" runat="server" Text="Ex-Lease" NavigateUrl="/Computers/Ex-Lease/index.aspx" /></div>
                    <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlClearance" runat="server" Text="Clearance" NavigateUrl="/search.aspx?S=Clearance+Item&picture=0" /></div>
                    <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlRepairs" runat="server" Text="Repairs" NavigateUrl="/Christchurch-Computer-Repairs-and-Service.aspx" /></div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pnlShop" CollapsedSize="32" ExpandedSize="192" Collapsed="True" ExpandControlID="lblShopBtn" CollapseControlID="lblShopBtn" AutoCollapse="false" AutoExpand="False" ScrollContents="True" ExpandDirection="Vertical" />
                 </div>
             <div class="Nav-Item">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlAccount" runat="server" >
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Header"><asp:Label ID="lblAccBtn" runat="server" Text="Account" /></div>
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlLogInOut" runat="server" Text="Login" /></div>
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlRegDetails" runat="server" Text="Register" /></div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe2" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pnlAccount" CollapsedSize="32" ExpandedSize="96" Collapsed="True" ExpandControlID="lblAccBtn" CollapseControlID="lblAccBtn" AutoCollapse="false" AutoExpand="False" ScrollContents="True" ExpandDirection="Vertical" />
                </div>
             <div class="Nav-Item">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlContact" runat="server" >
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Header"><asp:Label ID="lblContBtn" runat="server" Text="Contact Us" /></div>
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:Hyperlink ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="0800 165 800" NavigateUrl="Tel:0800165800" /></div>
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlRiccarton" runat="server" Text="Tower Junction" NavigateUrl="https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/GlobalPC/@-43.538377,172.605323,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xb97744d7c8d04fa0?hl=en" /></div>
                <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlShirley" runat="server" Text="Homebase" NavigateUrl="https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/GlobalPC/@-43.49374,172.660448,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x812c53f1576bdfd?hl=en" /></div>
                 <div class="Menu-Panel-Item"><asp:HyperLink ID="hlFeedback" runat="server" Text="Feedback Form" NavigateUrl="feedback.aspx" /></div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe3" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pnlContact" CollapsedSize="32" ExpandedSize="192" Collapsed="True" ExpandControlID="lblContBtn" CollapseControlID="lblContBtn" AutoCollapse="false" AutoExpand="False" ScrollContents="True" ExpandDirection="Vertical" />
                </div>
         </asp:Panel>

         <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" runat="server" class="Mobile-Body">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>   
         </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You need to post some code, or a link to your problem if you want to get some help. You're question doesn't provide any context.

Comment: I've added the code I'm using for my side menu but I don't currently have any code in my footer as it wasn't working and I got grumpy and deleted it. I'd like something similar to the panel extender setup but I'm not set on it if there's a better control to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3 Transformations to translate elements vertically. I do not have VS to run the .net code but here is a generic example.
Here is a demo of a menu at the bottom of the page. [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mupj4tc0/). Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><span>Menu Item 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Menu Item 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li><span>Menu Item 4</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</header>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
header {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: yellowgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.menu > li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
}
li span {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.menu > li > a {
    color: white;
}
li > ul {
    background-color: white;
    color: yellowgreen;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-50px);
    transform:translateY(-50px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
li > ul > li {
    border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0 10px;    
}
li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
    transform:translateY(-100%) -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. If I could give you a hearty handshake through the internet I probably still wouldn't cos it would be weird, but thank you very much for this. It's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a simple way of doing it.  Not following your existing code, but you can easily translate it for your needs.  Clearly a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhtg60qy/1/

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Nav One</li>
        <li>Nav Two</li>
        <li class="dropdown">Nav Three
            <ul class="dropdown__list">
                <li>Nav One</li>
                <li>Nav Two</li>
                <li>Nav Three</li>
                <li>Nav Four</li>
                <li>Nav Five</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Nav Four</li>
        <li>Nav Five</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.dropdown__list {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 180px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown__list {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
```